# Сумма значений в запросе

Tags: sql, interbase

```sql
select sum(SUMM_PRIH) 
from DOC_PR 
WHERE DATA_PRIH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' 
  and kod in ('020047', '020045')

UNION ALL

select sum(SUMM_OPL) 
from DOC_RA 
WHERE DATA_RASH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' 
  and kod in ('020112', '020116')
```

Получаю 2 значения,как можно посчитать сумму этих значений сразу в запросе ?

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически так:

```sql
SELECT ( select sum(SUMM_PRIH) 
         from DOC_PR 
         WHERE DATA_PRIH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' 
           and kod in ('020047', '020045')
        )
       +
       ( select sum(SUMM_OPL) 
         from DOC_RA 
         WHERE DATA_RASH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' 
           and kod in ('020112', '020116')
        ) total
FROM rdb$database
```

Только съест ли это Interbase... если нет, то пробуй

```sql
SELECT SUM(summ) total
FROM ( select sum(SUMM_PRIH) summ
       from DOC_PR 
       WHERE DATA_PRIH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' 
         and kod in ('020047', '020045')
     UNION ALL
       select sum(SUMM_OPL) 
       from DOC_RA 
       WHERE DATA_RASH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' 
         and kod in ('020112', '020116')
     ) total
```

Comment: Ошибка Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Unexpected end of command.

Comment: @Федотов Что, на оба запроса одна и та же ошибка, что ли?

Comment: Во втором запросе ошибка другая Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, char 6.
select.

Comment: @Федотов Ну увы. попробовать негде - я не знаю, где найти online fiddle для Interbase. Есть разве что для Firebird 3.0, но насколько оно совместимо, я не в курсе.

Comment: @Федотов перепроверьте первый вариант. Akina, взял на себя смелось исправить за вас.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Спасибо. Признаться, я даже не могу оценить эту правку - у меня про этот бранч СУБД представления весьма приблизительные.